# Mvc3 Jquery mobile dialog causes postback bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

If I open a jquery mobile dialog on my start page like this:

```asp
@Html.ActionLink("DialogPage", "DialogPage", "Home", null, new {data_rel="dialog" })
```

and then close the dialog using the X button, the start page is not reloaded which I think is the correct behavior.

But, if I navigate to a second page an open a jquery mobile dialog in the exact same way on the second page and using the X button to close the dialog, the dialog causes the second page to reload!

This is very easy to reproduce. Is this a bug or is it in some way an expected behavior?
This has been driving me crazy for days now(even for weeks). Please help me.

Edit: I dont know how to link pages in jsfiddle but here is my source code splitted into three pages (in bold headers):

**Start page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="c" data-role="header" data-position="inline" style="height: 70px; background-image: url('/Intranet/Mobile/Images/Bg_Main.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>Jquery mobile dialog bug?</h2>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="../Dialog/Dialog" data-rel="dialog">First dialog without postback behavior</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="/SecondPage/TheSecondPage">Link to second page containing a dialog with postback</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" class="ui-bar">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second Page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<link type="text/css" href="../Content/themes/base/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="c" data-role="header" data-position="inline" style="height: 70px; background-image: url('/Intranet/Mobile/Images/Bg_Main.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x">
<h1>
    header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<a href="../Dialog/Dialog" data-rel="dialog">Dialog with postback behavior</a>
<br />
<br />
</div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" class="ui-bar">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Dialog Page:**

```html
<div data-role="content"  data-theme="a" >
This is the dialog.
</div>
```

If there is anything else I can do to make this more easy, please let me know.

Edit 2: I think this is related to:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3549#issuecomment-4060809
containing a similar example.

Comment: If this is easy to reproduce, how about you post some of your code or even better put it in jsbin or jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell if this is your problem, but hopefully it is. :)  In the dialog page, make sure you DO NOT have this javascript running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
       // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
       // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), hence disabling it.
       $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

If you disable the Ajax, it does a full post back, which causes the page to refresh when you return.

Comment: This is not the problem. Ajax is enabled. Thanks anyway.